# Using ksort in PHP for SQL datetime format in reverse order

Tags: php, sql, date, ksort

Is it possible to use `ksort` to sort by maximum (ie. most recent) date with a SQL date time format? I have an array that is currently key-value where the key is the SQL date time format and the value is a string. When I do a `ksort` on it, it returns it by the least recent (I'm guessing the 'smallest') first and I want the reverse of that. Is there a flag that I don't know of that could set this or another function that could do it better?

Comment: [krsort](http://www.php.net/krsort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the reverse order of `ksort`, use [`krsort`](http://www.php.net/krsort).

Answer (score 0):

If the data is from SQL, why not have the DBMS sort the date data into the correct order?

Comment: good question! bunch of different tables that don't like to be joined together and aggregated / ordered the way i need it so i had to do a few different queries and add them to an array and then sort it.